# What piece of hardware handles keyframes (specifically AnimAll V-Col)

Tags: animation, keyframes, vertex-paint, hardware

I'm finding my current system is lacking (Trident 3 MSI) when it comes to doing V-Col masking keyframes for cell/toon shaded 3D animations.

Physically painting the masks in vertex color mode also is a bit laggy.

I'm aware when I ask Blender to keyframe vertex colors with the AnimAll addon it's taking a snap-shot of every single vertex of the selected model, which is why it takes a bit to do on higher poly models (which is super necessary if I want crisp shapes for the shading)

This isn't great for my work-flow, and want to know what I need to focus on hardware wise if I want a better performance.

Thanks ya'll!